# Install Linux Kernel modules

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, ipsec, strongswan

I'm setting up IPSec VPN and I have met an error which upon searching [I found](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/1069) the error actually means [required kernel modules](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/KernelModules) are missing. That prompted me to check that with `lsmod` and `kmod list` but both give an empty list.

That sounds to me like there is no loaded kernel module (sounds strange and unlikely to me but I have no other explanations) and so I need to load them in case they are there but not loaded or install them in case they are not there.

How do I do that?

I operate Debian 9 Box with Strongswan 5.1 as IPSec VPN Software

**UPDATE**

The error I get is this one

```
ipsec up conn-name
establishing CHILD_SA conn-name
generating CREATE_CHILD_SA request 937 [ SA No KE TSi TSr ]
sending packet: from <MY IP>[500] to <DEST IP>[500] (496 bytes)
received packet: from <DEST IP>[500] to <MY IP>[500] (352 bytes)
parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA response 937 [ N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA No KE TSi TSr ]
received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
received netlink error: Protocol not supported (93)
unable to add SAD entry with SPI c845df8d
received netlink error: Protocol not supported (93)
unable to add SAD entry with SPI 009fbcd3
unable to install inbound and outbound IPsec SA (SAD) in kernel
failed to establish CHILD_SA, keeping IKE_SA
sending DELETE for ESP CHILD_SA with SPI c845df8d
generating INFORMATIONAL request 938 [ D ]
sending packet: from <MY IP>[500] to <DEST IP>[500] (80 bytes)
received packet: from <DEST IP>[500] to <MY IP>[500] (80 bytes)
parsed INFORMATIONAL response 938 [ D ]
establishing connection 'conn-name' failed
```

Output for:
`lsmod`

```
#lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux xxx 2.6.32-042stab127.2 #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 16:41:44 MSK 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

also `cat /proc/modules` is empty

> Is this your own hardware, some virtualization

It is a VPS actually so I have no control over the hardware

Comment: It's good to downvote, but it is far better to say why so that the post can be improved. Downvoting without saying a word is counter-productive

Comment: can you add the error you're getting from Stronswan?   I've never seen a completely empty `lsmod` output.   Do you see any output from `cat /proc/modules`?

Comment: Completely empty `lsmod` output could indicate a shared kernel, one which you may not be able to change.  Is this your own hardware, some virtualization, or some hosted service?  If this is a hosted service, you may need to discuss with them what the limits of your service are, and they can possibly add the modules you need.  The output of `uname -a` might be interesting.

Comment: @GracefulRestart it is a shared VPS, so hardware isn't mine. But isn't VPS having ability to install anything including linux kernel?

Comment: @TimKennedy I have updated my question with details (empty output of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Linux xxx 2.6.32-042stab127.2 #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 16:41:44 MSK 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

That is definitely not a standard Debian 9 kernel. For a vanilla Debian 9, you would expect a 4.9.x series kernel.

Googling on the version number indicates this may be [an old OpenVZ/Virtuozzo kernel based on RHEL 6.](https://wiki.openvz.org/Download/kernel/rhel6/042stab127.2)

The kernel configuration is documented on that webpage, and indicates it should have the modules you need. Moreover, the kernel packages downloadable from that page definitely have the modules you need.

You should probably contact your VPS provider's support to find out what is going on with your environment and why the kernel modules seem to be missing. Maybe their VPS environment initialization procedure has a bug...

Comment: one more question. Since i have control of VPS, if I upgrade kernel manually, will it solve that

Comment: It should. You could  even download a .dpkg package of the current OpenVZ kernel (or an updated version of it) from the webpage I mentioned, and install that, if it turns out there is a requirement to use OpenVZ kernels in your VPS environment: (re?)installing a kernel package will also install the kernel modules for that kernel version.

Comment: have specific command for reinstalling?

Comment: If you have the package file at hand locally, `dpkg -i package_name.deb` should work. If it is available in a package repository provided by your VPS provider, then `apt-get install --reinstall package_name`. If the current kernel is not listed as an installed package, or you use a kernel version newer than what you currently have, you should omit the `--reinstall` option.

Comment: This redirected me to the right direction. I did a lot of things including using IPSec user space level instead of kernel level. Thank you!